# ImportError: No module named Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam

Tags: module, biopython

I am trying to run a script that uses the module Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam from Biopython. I am on a mac and I do have biopython installed.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: maybe you should post more infomation about your configuration, or minimal script that cause the error ? it might be a search path error

Answer (score 0):

import sys

print(sys.path)

to see if the path of that module is in the path, if not, you may need to update the path to include it.